# Two-tone font coloring in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, colors

I really like the look of two-tone buttons and fonts. I am thinking of when the top half of the font is one color and the bottom half is a variation on the same color. For an example see most of the buttons on an iPhone or the logo here http://ming.ly.

[image: mingly]

Is it possible to recreate this effect in CSS?

Comment: Do you have such fonts with you?? ie the .
ttf files??

Comment: No - it's more about the coloration than the actual choice of font.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[I managed to achieve that with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/nxFkG/)...

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;  
    color: #0f0;
    font-size: 28px;
}

div span {
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #f00;
    overflow: hidden;  
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    Hello
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNm8H/).

Tested in Firefox 5.

Keep in mind that it is not very semantic to repeat the text to be displayed once.

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you could ditch that inner `span` for something like this in the CSS...

```
div:before {
    content: "Hello";
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #f00;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c5X9/).

As far as I know, there is no value for `content` which will automatically use that element's text node. You could put it on the `title` attribute and use `attr(title)` (or any other attribute).

You could also use JavaScript to do the repeating.

```
var textRepeat = document.createElement('span'),
    textRepeatTextNode = document.createTextNode(element.firstChild.data);

element.appendChild(textRepeat.appendChild(textRepeatNode));
```

If the first child was not necessarily a text node, you could use `element.textContent || element.innerText`.

Comment: that's cool. Even if it's not great semantically. Could probably create javascript to automate it based on class, maybe.

Comment: @yitwail Yeah, repeating it twice kinda sucks. You could always do `div:after { content: 'Whatever' }` in the CSS.

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that, but then you're repeating it in css instead of html, it's still repeated. No need for that with JavaScript, but of course JavaScript may be unavailable. :(

Comment: I realise it is probably useless to ask but could the downvoter explain their reasoning? I'd like to take the opportunity to learn something or defend my CSS :)

Comment: @yitwail True, but as you can see there are downsides to most implementations.

Comment: Do you think it would hurt Google juju to have the same text twice in a row?

Comment: @Kevin Possibly. Try one of the alternate solutions if that worries you.

Comment: You can also retrieve the content from an attribute on the element via `content: attr(title)`. This would be slightly more semantic (and a lot more dynamic/flexible in my opinion). See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't well supported in 2011 when I wrote the answer :)

Answer (score 11):

I like @alex method very much. An alternative solution, supporting the white curve, but not cross browser I suppose* at the moment, could be the following:

**css**

```
#text {
    color: #5283CA;
    font-size: 70px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 210px;
}
#curve {
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(60deg);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 200px 20px 80px 20px;
    bottom: 270px;
    display: block;
    height: 1000px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    position: relative;
    right: 330px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="text">Mingly<div id="curve"></div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ENPnU/

I don't know any css property that can make a border curved. So I used, the rounded corners that I can create with css. Then I rotate the element with rounded corners (in this case the `#curve`) to the correct position, to seems like a white curve within the text. Then white opacity added.

*I tried it to make it work with ie, but I didn't find a complete solution, you can find the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/3TpeA/

Answer (score 0):

## 2023

You can use the css `linear-gradient` along with `background-clip: text` and `color: transparent` to achieve linear gradient colored text.

[image: Sample output]

```css
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      white 0%,
      white 50%,
      black 50%,
      black 100%
  );
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
```

```css
#a {
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: fit-content;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    blue 0%,
    blue 50%,
    white 50%,
    white 100%
  );
}

#a > span {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 48px;
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      white 0%,
      white 50%,
      black 50%,
      black 100%
  );
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <span>18</span>
</div>
```